# Rebooting Ubuntu on Windows without rebooting Windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to reboot the Ubuntu sub-system without restarting my system?

I tried to use the `shutdown` command after installing some updates, but that doesn't seem to be an option here.

[image: WSL. Reboot required. Unable to shutdown system]

The screenshot text :

```
~$ bin/rcheck.sh
Reboot required.
~$ sudo shutdown -r now
shutdown: Unable to shutdown system
```

Comment: Rebooting (standard) WSL is not a thing. Simply put, a WSL distribution is just a container (like Docker) with a shell. Even with WSL 2, rebooting the VM does nothing to a distribution.

Answer (score 615, accepted):

You cannot reboot a distro with a single command. You must shut down and boot up the distro with two commands. If you run **`wsl.exe`** instead of `wsl`, then it works both in WSL Bash & CMD.

*View the list of distros and their current state:*

```
wsl.exe -l -v
```

***Shutdown everything:*** <kbd>[Build 18917+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/)</kbd>

```
wsl.exe --shutdown
```

*Terminate a specific distro:* <kbd>[Windows 1903+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#wslexe)</kbd>

```
wsl.exe -t <DistroName>
```

*Boot up the default distro (marked with `*`):*

```
wsl.exe
```

*Boot up a specific distro:*

```
wsl.exe -d <DistroName>
```

---

### Older versions

```bash
# PowerShell (admin)
Restart-Service LxssManager

# or CMD (admin)
net stop LxssManager
net start LxssManager
```

[image]

Comment: why `net` instead of `sc`, as in @llinfeng's answer

Comment: `net` worked in cmd (with admin). Just tested that my bat-file with `sc` did not work in Windows OS Build 1809.

Comment: @Gaia  the `net` command is the legacy tool for managing Windows services and networks, pre-PowerShell

Comment: I had issues in an Admin CMD on my machine (Windows 10 build 17763) with the `net` command (`net stop LxxManager` seems to hang). Since I stay away from PowerShell (since I have WSL), the `sc` command (query/stop/start) get the job done without any issues on that same Admin CMD window. I think it currently is the preferred API for the Service Control Manager?

Comment: I'm using the newest Windows Insider with WSL 2 and tried to use commands like
`C:\Users\xxx>wsl -l -v` showing that three are "Ubuntu", "docker-desktop" and "docker-desktop-data"

As in my case, there is also the newest docker running so wsl -shutdown works, but it also closes my docker environment

After trial and error, I found that wsl -t "Ubuntu" works, but sometimes it takes time or is not reliable?  Once it worked when I started command shell with admin rights.

Comment: Working perfectly with `wsl2` !

Comment: That `-t` is not correct at all. At least when the OS needs reboot. When you terminate it with `-t` and run again, it will still need reboot...

Comment: Since there is no reboot, as a newbie, I had problems getting the newly installed Linux back on.

Comment: Is that a clean shutdown, like `shutdown -h`? IOW: if I have processes running, will they be given a chance to clean up?

Comment: If I do wsl.exe --shutdown, does that reboot Ubuntu, or merely shut it down?

Comment: I just tested it. This only shuts down Ubuntu - it does NOT reboot Ubuntu. The question asks for a way to REBOOT the system. If the only way to do this involves running "wsl --shutdown" and then manually booting up Ubuntu again, please indicate this in your answer.

Comment: Some years later ... The command `wsl` within WSL doesn't work for me, while `wsl.exe` does. So e. g. `wsl.exe --shutdown` will effectively shutdown WSL *within* WSL.

Comment: yeah i had that originally in my answer, but someone edited it

Answer (score 115):

At an administrative PowerShell prompt: `Restart-Service LxssManager`

Comment: @RajeshS It may be short but it does answer the question.

Comment: I like it. Easy to remember, autocompletes with tab well enough. Amusing to see how well Windows got its service model down right from the beginning.

Comment: I just get this repeatedly `WARNING: Waiting for service 'LxssManager (LxssManager)' to stop...`

Comment: This works perfectly. Just start your powershell with admin rights first.

Comment: I have the same issue to Chris.

Comment: If you get a problem where you're waiting for the service to stop, you need to terminate the WSL VM first with ``wsl -d distro_name --shutdown`` and ``wsl -t distro_name``, then ``Restart-Service LxssManager`` should work properly.  This is the "cleanest" solution, imo, that depends on Microsoft's tools to do the major work for you.

Comment: this is the only method that works when WSLg is freezed and unresponsive, using `wsl --shutdown` is not enough.

Answer (score 39):

Since Windows 10 version 1803, closing all WSL terminal windows won't kill background processes by default, unless the file `/var/run/reboot-required` is present. This file will be automatically created by apt on Ubuntu when an update requires a reboot, but if you want to manually reboot the subsystem, you can create the file yourself:

```
sudo touch /var/run/reboot-required
```

I haven't tested this on other distributions available in the Microsoft Store. An alternative solution is to kill all processes yourself:

```
sudo killall -r '.*'
```

Comment: Do you know what I can do force a required reboot? I want to test the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to `sudo`: `sudo killall -r '.*'`

Comment: @Louis I see you've already accepted it, but you can do `sudo touch /var/run/reboot-required`. In fact, it seems the presence of the file causes WSL to kill all background processes and shut down the subsystem when all terminal windows are closed, so you can abuse that as well.

Comment: `killall` worked perfectly for me. Didn't need to touch `reboot-required`.

Comment: Touching `reboot-required` (and closing all terminals) didn't do anything for me. In the end, I just did `wsl --shutdown` and `wsl -d <Distro>` (example: `wsl -d Ubuntu`; to get the list, use `wsl -l`).

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to always work. The other answers here work *sometimes*, but not always. Note you still need to shut it down from Windows after running this command but this command gives Windows 10 control if it is lost.

Answer (score 25):

Just open a cmd window as adminstrator and run these commands to restart it.

```
net stop LxssManager
net start LxssManager
```

Comment: Add some seconds between those two command. e.g. `timeout /t 3` command (add 3 seconds).

Comment: This duplicates samdd's answer from August.

Comment: Doesn't work... stays in "stopping" status. when I try to run it again I get "The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later."... never finishes. Always hangs after I run an rsync command from batch like "bash -c 'rsync....'". This is a nightmare.

Comment: "The LxssManager service is stopping.........................................................................
The LxssManager service could not be stopped." :-/

Answer (score 12):

The following allows a shutdown from within WSL2 using the command
`wslreboot` (or any custom command).

*Technically*, `wslshutdown` would be more appropriate for the code below:

#### Create alias:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

#### Add line:

```
alias wslreboot='history -a && cmd.exe /C wsl --shutdown'
```

`history -a` ensures that the bash command history us saved before shutdown.

#### Enable Alias:

Restart WSL

```
cmd.exe /C wsl --shutdown
```

or type

```
source .bash_aliases
```

#### Use

now you can type

```
wslreboot
```

to shutdown

---

I'm thinking you could use a variation of the above to run a batch file with the lines:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl
```

for a proper restart.

Comment: I wasted precious minutes reading documentation and figuring this out on my own before finding your answer :) Thanks

Comment: Nice answer, learned something new.

Comment: Actually, PowerShell 7 detects the abrupt exit as an error.

Answer (score 10):

Simply exiting the shell with `exit` and reopening seems to do the trick. **The shell needs to be run as admin.**

```
Louis@ATHENA:~$ bin/rcheck.sh
Reboot not necessary.

Louis@ATHENA:~$ bin/update.sh
[sudo] password for Louis:
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0 openssl
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libssl1.0.0 amd64 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 [830 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openssl amd64 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 [489 kB]
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21) ...
Del libssl1.0.0 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.20 [830 kB]
Del openssl 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.20 [489 kB]

Louis@ATHENA:~$ bin/rcheck.sh
Reboot required.

Louis@ATHENA:~$ exec bash -l
Louis@ATHENA:~$ bin/rcheck.sh
Reboot required.

Louis@ATHENA:~$ exit

Louis@ATHENA:~$ bin/rcheck.sh
Reboot not necessary.
Louis@ATHENA:~$
```

Comment: This does not work anymore.

Comment: @Dakkaron - It did when the question was submitted.

Comment: That's why I said "anymore". The information that this post is outdated is important, so other people who have the problem right now don't need to try it to find out that it does not work. I am not sure how things are handled here, but on Stackoverflow an answer is not only supposed to help the person who asked the question, but also all others who are looking for solutions for the same problem.

Comment: Specifically, it does not work since `Windows 10 Build 17046`. @Louis would you mind editing this into your answer?

Comment: Works for me on build 17134.

Comment: Worked for me on 1909 (18363). So the answer is still valid. Make sure you run it in an elevated prompt.

Comment: @Dakkaron You're right, but one of the comments pointed out it will work in an elevated prompt, and I verified this before deciding to delete to leave this here.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a `*.bat` file, and running it does the rebooting within 10 seconds. (I am amazed by how fast things get reloaded. And, please advise if my approach will cause serious trouble in the long run.)

Put the following two lines in a `WSL_reboot.bat` file, and run it every time you need to reboot the WSL on Windows 10.

```
net stop LxssManager
net start LxssManager
```

*Update note*: per my recent "upgrade" of Windows OS, the Build 1809 does not like `sc` command anymore.

Side note: one need to reboot the WSL "kernel" when he/she format a lettered-drive through Windows Explorer. Haven't quite solve the by-product, though, where `ls` command will get the following error. [Related-post-from-WSL@Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1372); [Related-post-from-the-Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345598/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-environment). Will drop a link if I manage to solve the by-product bug.

```
ls: 'System Volume Information': Permission denied
...
d--x--x--x 1 llinfeng llinfeng       512 Jan 15 11:00 'System Volume Information'/
...
```

Comment: why `sc` instead of `net`, as in @samdd's answer

Comment: I guess `net` was not working with my Windows 10 at the time? `sc` must have worked back then. I should have specified the windows build number.

Answer (score 0):

From inside the WSL/Ubuntu terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
to shut down.

Restart ("reboot") the same way you started WSL the last time.

Comment: Well, "sort of".  The reality is much more complex.  WSL will only actually "shut down" the controlling distribution and/or VM in certain scenarios.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436045/1165986) for the current status.  Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1353286/1165986), where I give a similar answer to yours but with the caveats ;-).

Answer (score -2):

What I have done is:

- Enter this command in the command line you've opened in Admin mode: `wsl.exe --install`
- Restart your machine

Then Windows will be updated accordingly. After that, the error gone. The Linux account can be created normally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but this doesn't remotely answer the question. The OP already has WSL installed, and merely wanted a way to reboot the Linux subsystem without going through a full Windows reboot.