# can I share my SSH keys between WSL and Windows?

Tags: bash, ssh, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to move from using Powershell to Bash on Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux or WSL). For the purpose of using GIT, I've set up my SSH keys in `C:/Users/User/.ssh`. I then logged into Bash, and created a symlink `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/User/.ssh/ ~/.ssh/` in order to (in theory) use the same ssh keys from both shells.

When running git, however, I always get an error: `Bad owner or permissions on /home/user/.ssh/config`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

SSH requires sane permissions on the private keys and you are not able to achieve that while symlinking to different filesystem (windows). The manual page for `ssh` explains that quite clearly:

> `~/.ssh/id_rsa`
>
> Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain sensitive data and should be readable by the user but **not accessible by others (read/write/execute)**.  ssh will simply ignore a private key file if it is accessible by others.

You can most probably copy the private keys and set appropriate permissions, if you want to "share the keys".

Comment: thank you. And there is no way I could share the same user between the two systems?

Comment: copying the keys doesn't work. they still have their old ownership & permissions. Using chmod and chown silently fails.

Answer (score 13):

To build on @ChadT's helpful [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334839/1221874), here's what worked for me.

Open your distro, and create or modify the `/etc/wsl.conf` file to include the `automount` options below:

```
$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
options = "metadata,umask=022,fmask=111"
```

These options ensure that files in the mounted system are given proper user and group ownership, and that they have sensible default permissions (as opposed to everything getting `777`).

Close the distro, [wait about 10 seconds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf) for the background subsystem to stop running, and reopen the distro.

Navigate to your mounted C: drive at `/mnt/c/Users/<user>`, and set the proper permissions on the `.ssh` directory and key files, as required by SSH:

```
$ cd /mnt/c/Users/<user>
$ chmod 700 .ssh
$ chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 644 .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Finally, navigate to your distro's home drive, backup or remove any existing `.ssh` directory, and create a symlink back to your C: drive's `.ssh` directory:

```
$ cd ~
$ mv .ssh .ssh_orig
$ ln -s /mnt/c/Users/plw1845/.ssh/ .ssh
```

You should now be able to fully share your Windows SSH config, hosts, and keys with your WSL distro, while maintaining them in a single place.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution which mounts the `.ssh` directory directly and doesn't require changing `/etc/wsl.conf` to enable the `metadata` option (which can be a bit heavyweight, in my opinion).

By default, most/all Linux distros read and process [the `fstab` file](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/etc-fstab) on startup, to automatically mount filesystems. WSL 2 [does so as well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/). And since Windows drives and folders [can be mounted directly in WSL using DrvFs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/), we can combine them to automatically sync the `.ssh` directory between OSes.

Open your Linux distro and edit the `/etc/fstab` file as root (e.g. with `sudo nano /etc/fstab`). Add the following line at the end:

```
C:\Users\<your Windows username>\.ssh\ /home/<your Linux username>/.ssh drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off,umask=0077,fmask=0177 0 0
```

where you've replaced `<your Windows username>` and `<your Linux username>` appropriately. The other mount flags will ensure the permissions on the `.ssh` directory are correct. Then [restart your WSL distro](https://superuser.com/a/1347725/585210) and voilà, all your SSH keys and config will be automagically available in Linux. Any changes will be synchronized.

Comment: This really works on my Win10 19042!

Comment: This is great (tested and works on Windows 10 19044.2130

Comment: Also, If for some reason this doesn't work for you, make sure you're using WSL2.

Answer (score 7):

You need to mount your windows filesystem using the `DrvFS` file system with the `metadata` option which allows Linux permissions to coexist with Windows files by storing them in file metadata.

`sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata`

This will allow you to use your SSH Keys across both Operating Systems.

Further reading:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

And yet more reading on how to configure `WSL` to apply this setting everytime it starts:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/

Comment: Hi Chad, this is interesting. I no longer have a dual boot system so I'm unable to test if it works for me and therefore can't mark it as the right answer. But I can upvote.

Comment: @bluppfisk fwiw I am using this method to share ssh keys across Windows/Linux and it is working great!

Comment: just to be clear, you are still simply copying the files not sharing them, right? As Jakuje notes, the permissions of symlinks seem incompatible with `ssh` restrictions and I have just encountered the expected "unprotected file" warnings... If you're able to somehow keep only one key in either WSL or Windows and then create a shortcut/symlink that works with SSH, please do let me know!

Comment: @FonsMA - No this isn't copying, it's mounting the files with additional metadata to that the permission info is carried through.

Comment: yes, my C drive has Linux metadata and I can set whatever permissions I want. But I still need to keep an exact copy of `my_key.rsa` both under `/mnt/c/Users/fons/.ssh/` and `/home/fons/.ssh/` for stuff I run out of WSL (like my Rstudio Server ssh tunnelling) and stuff that runs on Windows (like Visual Studio Code). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Based on solution from [Gabriel Majeri](https://superuser.com/users/585210/gabriel-majeri), perform the following script in your WSL distro:

```
# Create .ssh directory in home directory with proper permission
mkdir -m 700 ~/.ssh

# Get Windows user name
WINUSER=`cmd.exe /c 'echo %USERNAME%' | tr -d '\r'`

# Add a permanent mount entry for Windows user .ssh directory
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
C:\Users\\$WINUSER\.ssh\ /home/$USER/.ssh drvfs rw,noatime,uid=`id -u`,gid=`id -g`,case=off,umask=0077,fmask=0177 0 0
EOF

# Mount the .ssh
sudo mount /home/$USER/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your Windows `.ssh` folder into WSL. Mount the C:/ drive to WSL, then put the following in your `~/.bashrc`

```bash
# Copy .ssh folder from G:\ to WSL and set correct access.
# The access is important, because extra access on config file
# will prevent it from working.
rm -rf ~/.ssh_new
cp -r /mnt/g/.ssh ~/.ssh_new \
  && chmod 400 ~/.ssh_new/*.ppk \
  && chmod 600 ~/.ssh_new/config \
  && chmod 644 ~/.ssh_new/known_hosts \
  && chmod 644 ~/.ssh_new/*.pub \
  && chmod 700 ~/.ssh_new/ \
  && HOME=$(pwd) \
  && wsl.exe -u root /bin/sh -c "rm -rf $HOME/.ssh" \
  && mv ~/.ssh_new ~/.ssh
```

This assumes that your public keys end in `.pub` and your private keys end in `.ppk`. You can modify the command according to your needs.

#### Update (and probably a better solution)

Running the above from your .bashrc will work when opening an instance of WSL, but it will fail when opening a WSL-connected terminal via Visual Studio Code. I think VSCode has a protection that prevents privilege escalation via `wsl.exe -u root`.

An alternative is to use a script and run it manually when you need to update the .ssh folder.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USER_HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)

# Copy .ssh folder from G:\ to WSL and set correct access.
# The access is important, because extra access on config file
# will prevent it from working.
cd $USER_HOME
rm -rf ./.ssh_new
cp -r /mnt/g/.ssh ./.ssh_new \
  && chown -R $SUDO_USER:$SUDO_USER ./.ssh_new \
  && chmod 400 ./.ssh_new/*.ppk \
  && chmod 600 ./.ssh_new/config \
  && chmod 644 ./.ssh_new/known_hosts \
  && chmod 644 ./.ssh_new/*.pub \
  && chmod 755 ./.ssh_new/ \
  && rm -rf ./.ssh \
  && mv ./.ssh_new ./.ssh
```

Comment: Allowing root to SSH into any system is a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: @Ramhound If you're root, you already have access to create such a script and call it yourself... It's not a vulnerability, since root has access to view the .ssh directory of any user. Also, the script doesn't copy the keys into `/root` unless you call the script as root; it copies it into the calling user's home directory. The entire question here is about sharing SSH keys between Windows and WSL. That obviously will give the WSL root user access to the keys, whether you mount your .ssh folder or copy the keys.

Comment: The default user within WSL absolutely shouldn’t be the root user.