# Rebooting WSL in Windows 1803

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1803

In past versions of Windows 10, WSL could be exited by [closing all active terminals](https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows?newreg=c120c63f79154c6d8c3da50b90b1afdf) but with the introduction of [background tasks in WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/) this no longer works. Is there a way to exit WSL without rebooting the host system?

Comment: Stop the background task from wsl.

Comment: Background task create a process with `wslhost.exe` executable. One may kill that process but the result will be catastrophic.

Comment: I suppose setting up an alias to kill all background tasks and exit would work, it just feels like far too much of a hack. But if that's what it takes, that's what I'll do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is.

As an Administrator restart the windows Service "LxssManager" on Windows 10.
This does a clean boot of the WSL.
The services in the Linux Subsystem - for example xrdp - must be restarted if not enabled for autostart.

Answer (score 14):

A Powershell solution

```
Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service
```

Comment: The most elegan solution in my opinion.
Don't forget that you have to start the PowerShell with administrator privilege tough.

Answer (score 12):

1. <kbd>WIN+R</kbd> -> `services.msc`
2. Find `LxssManager`

   [image]
3. Right-click -> `Restart`

   [image]

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers mention, specifically for windows 1803, the following should work from powershell or cmd:

```
net stop LxssManager
```

As highlighted by @Ramhound, only for newer versions, which have wsl 2, you can also run this from powershell or cmd:

#### shutdown all instances:

```
wsl.exe --shutdown
```

#### shutdown a specific instance (e.g. Ubuntu):

```
wsl.exe -t Ubuntu
```

#### to show the current list of instances:

```
wsl.exe -l
```

Comment: To my knowledge *wsl.exe* does not exist on Windows 10 version 1803