# ssh channel hangs after authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Server **ranger** has just yesterday become unresponsive upon ssh login, after months of working as expected. Authentication succeeds, but then `-vvv` logging reveals an incredibly long delay being set on the channel established for the session:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ranger ([192.168.1.115]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env DOCKER_HOST
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env NAME
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env HOSTTYPE
debug3: Ignored env _JAVA_OPTIONS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: channel_handler: chan 0: skip for 713631 more seconds
debug3: channel_handler: first channel unpauses in 713631 seconds
debug3: channel_handler: chan 0: skip for 713631 more seconds
debug3: channel_handler: first channel unpauses in 713631 seconds
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: channel_handler: chan 0: skip for 713631 more seconds
debug3: channel_handler: first channel unpauses in 713631 seconds
debug3: channel_handler: chan 0: skip for 713631 more seconds
debug3: channel_handler: first channel unpauses in 713631 seconds
debug3: channel_handler: chan 0: skip for 713631 more seconds
debug3: channel_handler: first channel unpauses in 713631 seconds
```

The same occurs on other accounts on this machine, including completely new ones using password authentication (so presumably that rules out `.bashrc` problems and so on).  Likewise, attempting to invoke a completely different command (`ssh -vvv user@ranger 'ls ~'`) yields the same.

The client and server are on the same ethernet network, attached to the same switch.

Client: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Server: Ubuntu 16.04.4, OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: Have you tried restarting the `sshd` process?  Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Can you test with PuTTY as client?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yes, and yes. But, it seems it's a client problem!

Comment: @cemerick How about clearing .ssh on the client temporarily?

Comment: @grawity I did, and was shocked to find that it worked. Likewise, a separate git/bash environment. (My usual environment is WSL.)

Comment: @TrippKinetics I had already done that; tried again, and still no luck.

Comment: @cemerick How about connecting from that client to a different server?

Comment: I just got the exact same error on Windows Bash (WSL) Ubuntu (2 million second plus unpause), and it seems that moving all the files out of ~/.ssh, closing all terminal windows, and then moving the files back fixed the issue. I have no idea what could have triggered this.

Comment: I had the same issue with WSL, I ended up having to remove and reinstall it.

Answer (score 16):

I've just came to the same problem as above while using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and the solutions mentioned before did not work for me.

I finally resolved the problem by rebooting the WSL. At the PowerShell in the administrative mode just type in: `Restart-Service LxssManager`

I was inspired by the solution given in [Rebooting Ubuntu on Windows without rebooting Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows)

Comment: I can confirm this solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm also on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). Killing all running instances of `C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe` fixed it. Before that, opening new bash instances didn't work.

I assume that others have tried rebooting, without success, so I don't think this solution is widely applicable, but hopefully my data point will help someone figure out what's going on.

I had several bash instances open, and some of them had been open for weeks, so maybe a shared exponential backoff value wasn't getting reset. Earlier today, Windows's network icon was (falsely) reporting that I didn't have network access, so maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: The large values do indeed look like an exponential backoff problem. I am currently in the same situation and killing all bash instances did not fix it. I am using connection sharing in my SSH config, so maybe there is still a reference somewhere held by the OS. Following this, I remembered that I am using "wslbridge". Killing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this identical issue with WSL openSSH.  Every other ssh program had no problem logging into the local device.  I tried all the suggestions above with no success even completely uninstalling openSSH-client and reinstalling.

Then I tried the number one thing you're suppose to do when a computer is acting stupid.  Shut it off and turn it back on.  Everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer so much as a resolution: I removed and reinstalled ssh, and all's well. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue a couple of times. Inspired by Marc Ho's [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1320455/ssh-channel-hangs-after-authentication#comment2002561_1320455), I exited all my WLS sessions and it worked right away on the next session I opened. I did not need to remove files from .ssh, though.

I suspect an orphaned lock between sleeps and/or network changes. I happen to have a network drive as Home in my Windows that could be contributing to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced this issue when the ssh windows terminal got hanged

```
Remote Machine : 14.04 ubuntu
Local Machine : WSL(ubuntu 20.04)
SSH Client : openssh
```

So previously my env var `LANG` was `c.utf-8` and I changed it to `en_US.UTF-8`