# How to (automatically) install gradle 5.6(+) on WSL Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, powershell

### Scenario

While trying to install gradle 5.5+ from a powershell script in windows, on WSL Ubuntu 16.04, I experienced mild technical difficulties.

### Attempts

1. Following approach 2. of https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/06/install-gradle-ubuntu-16-04/, SDKMAN would not be registred from powershell with `sdk help` even though it would inside the WSL itself. And `Restart-Service LxssManager` from [Rebooting Ubuntu on Windows without rebooting Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows) did not ensure SDKMAN was registered either.
2. https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-18-04/ required Setting up Environment Variables with `export` which has been challenging for me in combination with piping outputs in the past.
3. Same argument as in 2: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-16-10
4. https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/06/install-gradle-ubuntu-16-04/ requests writing with `vi` which can be non-trivial with powershell.
5. `sudo apt install gradle` installed gradle 2.10 instead of 5.5+.
6. [This github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/773) instructions returned couldn't find gradle 3.1

### Question

How can one automatically install gradle V5.5+ in WSL Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows with a (powershell) script?

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found by combining the following two instructions:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/773
- https://wtanaka.com/node/8079

Yielding instruction set:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get install gradle-ppa
```

Which, converted into a powershell script (that in the first line installs the WSL Ubuntu 16.04) can look like:

```
lxrun /install /y
bash -c "yes | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa"
bash -c "yes | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle"

bash -c "yes | sudo apt-get update"

bash -c "yes | sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre"
bash -c "yes | sudo apt-get install gradle-ppa"
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: You should NOT have to use a PPA to install OpenJDK.  "openjdk-8-jre" should be available in Ubuntu 16.04 by default.    See https://askubuntu.com/q/464755/963 for a discussion about this for 14.04 (and the implicit resolving on 16.04).  Also I would suggest you use 18.04 instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you, after testing and verifying the gradle 5.5+ installation functionallity of the powershell script, without using a PPA to install `openjdk-8-jre`, but a normal `apt install openjdk-8-jre`, I will incorporate your suggested improvement in both the commands and the powershell script. Thank you for your suggestion, I would very much like to do so, yet I have not yet determined how to automatically install `WSL Ubuntu 18.04` from windows (powershell).