# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down Failed to talk to init daemon

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opensuse, wsl2

his is what happens when I try to put in:

sudo reboot

and:

/sbin/reboot

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down Failed to talk to init daemon.
I use the OpenSUSE wsl.
Is there any way to fix this???

Comment: what about `shutdown -r now` ?

Comment: @mashuptwice same error

Comment: I don't  think Linux system control commands like `reboot` can work under WSL.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Does this answer your question? [Rebooting Ubuntu on Windows without rebooting Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows)

Comment: yes, thank you!