# WSL stops responding

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using `wsl --install -d ubuntu`.

But sometimes it stops responding and freezes when I've been in Linux for a long time.

Windows Version: 21H2.
CPU virtualization, Linux subsystem, and virtual machine platform are enabled.

Comment: When it "freezes", I assume there's no error message, right?  The next time it freezes, try opening PowerShell or CMD and then run `wsl ~` a second time.  Does it start?  If so, add the output of `ps n -efH` to the question.  That may give you some idea what's going on.  You may be able to `kill <pid>` the offending processes from another WSL window and get the first one to start again.

Comment: Also, it probably won't matter but is this Windows 10 or 11?  Both have "21H2" releases.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue I'm using wsl2 with ubuntu and zsh/oh-my-zsh + starship prompt 

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎8/‎23/‎2022
OS build 22000.1098
Serial number PF3ZL4QL
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.1098.0
```

Comment: Moreover. VScode Server for wsl also hangs and says "reload window" as being unresponsive which indicates that's a wsl problem. 
Sometimes, opening cmd in administrator mode and issueing `wsl --shutdown` works but not everytime
There are resources to to restart wsl 
- https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-reboot-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux-in-windows-10.html
- https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows

Comment: I've experienced the same thing (W11, 22H2). Seems to be tied to my laptop or desktop resuming from some form of sleep. The restart of the VM doesn't seem to be possible (`wsl` command just hangs elevated prompt or not) - reboot is the only one I can recover.

Comment: FWIW, instead of reboot you should be able to kill wslservice.exe

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds tried your suggestion, by killing a bash script that ran an ssh session (only), and got my original terminal back. Will continue observing to see if this happens when the terminal is just sitting idle.
Can confirm that the plan9 file server is not the culprit (in my case).
https://superuser.com/questions/1749690/what-is-this-weird-process-i-see-in-wsl-called-plan9

Comment: I'm seeing this too (Win 11 22h2, WSL2), but when it freezes, I don't have to reboot as others have said, I can just launch another instance. It doesn't fix the frozen instance, but I can at least resume what I was doing without any serious interruption to my workflow.

Comment: Plain vanilla Debian instance (both 11 and 12): same thing. Just hangs for a minute, and then comes back to life. It feels exactly like when the garbage collector was triggered in the C64 BASIC to tidy up strings...

Comment: I get this with WSL2 on Windows 10. I usually notice because everything starts running slow, and it turns out the Vmmem process is using 100% CPU. I am unable to shutdown WSL with `wsl --shutdown` because nothing gets a response in the terminal. The only way I can end it is by ending WSL in Task Manager, but thereafter `wsl` commands still don't receive any response in the Windows terminal. Only a Windows restart works.

Comment: same story, restart of Windows is the only option so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Hyper-V (**if disabled**)
And install WSL app from Microsoft Store may help
And also execute

```
$ sudo apt autoremove -y
```

Will delete unused packages that will help free disk space and also make WSL faster

And if it hanged you can execute from PowerShell

```
PS C:\Users\user> wsl --shutdown
```

To completely close it and then open taskbar search to open Ubuntu and WSL will completely restart