# WLS 2 on Windows 11 (Ubuntu 22) freezes after ~15 hours of running

Tags: windows, ubuntu, freeze, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

This appears to be a similar problem to [this unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/1713488/wsl-stops-responding/1739919?noredirect=1#comment2695256_1739919).

Usually I have a `tail -f nohup.out` command running in one pane, and `nvidia-smi` running in the other pane (refreshing every second) to keep an eye on GPU temperatures. The `nohup` is a script running Blender 3D renders using GPUs via CUDA.

When this happens, the pane with the `nvidia-smi` is still working correctly, it keeps refreshing, and I can even exit and write other commands which will work. However every pane with the `tail -f` is completely frozen. Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only prints `C` in the pane, and the process itself is clearly stopped (no more logs coming through the `tail-f`, no resources utilized at all).

After this happens, no new WSL instance can be started anymore, even if I run `wsl ~` in a CMD window; nor does it if I open another Terminal window.  It just opens an empty terminal window, but the shell prompt never appears. The only way to recover seems to be restarting the machine :-/.

This is Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL on Windows 11 installed just a couple months ago.
`wsl --version` returns:

```
WSL version: 1.1.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.49
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1413
```

Comment: Wow; this is just an incredible stroke of luck that I found your question, but bad luck that I'm seeing it a month after you wrote it.  I was looking at things I'd flagged, and randomly clicked on your "answer" (comment) on the other similar question.  I just recently got 10k reputation, so I can now see deleted answers, and I noticed that you commented that you would create a new question.  I was surprised because I typically see all WSL questions -- but because you didn't tag this one [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], I never saw it.

Comment: So let's start with the obvious question - Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds! Thank you for your interest in this question. Unfortunately I haven’t run other 3D renders since that last one so I’m not really sure :/ I could try another run this Friday and see what happens? Did the problem ever resolve for you?

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, I can confirm that the problem is still happening to this day!

Comment: What does a `wsl --version` return?  It's possible that it will return just the help text, which is also useful information.  If it returns actual version information, would you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1739927/edit) it into your question?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, thank you for your interest in this. I updated the question with the output of `wsl --version`, I hope it gives us a clue!

Comment: Well, not much unfortunately.  You are on the latest-and-greatest.  I do myself see occasional freezes like this, where (a) one WSL distribution stops responding, (b) the others are still usable, (c) no more can be started.  I'd definitely consider it a bug, but I generally don't have to reboot -- I go into Task Manager, kill off any "Windows Subsystem for Linux" processes there, and I'm usually able to get back to WSL-as-usual.  Since you have something more reproducible, you may want to [open an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you @NotTheDr01ds, I’ll look into that! i have to figure out a way to prevent this from happening as it can result in many hours of rendering time lost until i realize the freeze happened :/

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10155