# What is this weird process I see in WSL called “plan9?”

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, process, wsl2

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu on Windows 11 and there is a weird process called `plan9` I see with `htop`.

Here is a picture of it.

[image: Screenshot.]

`ps ax` output:

```
4 ?        Sl     0:00 plan9 --control-socket 5 --log-level 4 --server-fd 6 --log-truncate
```

Can anyone explain what that is? I found nothing on the internet about that.

Comment: Yes; It's normal. Plan 9 is `Plan 9 file server` also known as `9P protocol file server` and allows Windows to access the files contained within WSL2. Relevant Google search [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=plan9+WSL)

Comment: Okay, thank you! Why do you think it wasn't shown before in htop and only just now started to do so?

Comment: Your question only indicate it did show up in the htop result.

Comment: Yes it did show up there but it didn't use to do so. Today was the first time seeing it there and I've looked before. So do you have any idea why does it show up there now and not before?

Comment: The service likely wasn't running.  Did you recently installed WSL2?

Answer (score 8):

It's a really good question -- I hadn't noticed this yet, but I hadn't upgraded WSL in a few days.  This is a very recent change (last week) in the latest WSL releases.

As mentioned in the comments, WSL uses the 9P protocol to share files between Windows and WSL.  However, this process only appears starting in WSL [0.70.4](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.70.4).  Although there is nothing mentioned about it in the 0.70.4 release notes, the 0.70.5 notes mention  fixing a race condition in (what is likely) this component.

It's definitely injected by WSL itself, so nothing to worry about, but it would be nice to know what the purpose is, since it is *new*.  Several theories that I can think of:

- This is related to the recent Systemd changes in WSL.
- This change fixed a WSL issue -- Although I don't see any 9P issues that were recently closed in the WSL GitHub repo.
- This change might be designed to give the WSL team more control over changes to the 9P component, where previous releases might have been tied to Windows components/functionality.
- This change (hopefully!) will allow the WSL team to improve the performance of 9P when accessing Windows files through WSL2.  The *extremely* poor performance has been one of the few reasons to use WSL1 over WSL2 (when that feature is needed).  I tested this under 0.70.5, and this change definitely *doesn't* improve performance, but maybe it sets the stage for a future update where that will happen.

But, until someone from Microsoft tells us more, these are just theories.

Comment: My theory is it's used to handle in use files by Windows. I've noticed more "you don't have admin rights to delete this file" when said file is in use by Windows. Nothing technical to back this up. Only going on personal experience and my workflow.

Answer (score 2):

this is in fact taken form the plan 9 OS which was developed at Bell labs to replace Unix  "9P is a generic, medium-agnostic, byte-oriented protocol that provides for messages delivered between a server and a client"

[plan9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs)

Comment: I can understand the downvote because it doesn't offer much proof that *this* 9P and plan9 is really related to the other 9P and Plan9 (IIRC a brainchild of Dennis Ritchie, of C language fame), but it does sound credible. Actually it's exactly what I was also thinking when I noticed the name.

Comment: And this makes it even more credible: https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/9p.html