# Windows WSL (using ksh) hangs after random idle periods

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu on Windows 10 with WSL.  My shell is KornShell (ksh).  After idle periods of not using the shell - can be several hours or just a few minutes - it becomes unresponsive. A given shell can be in use for several weeks without issue, or it can hang several times a day. I've been unable to detect any correlation with other Windows activity.

Tried suggestions for restarting Ubuntu (e.g.: [Rebooting Ubuntu on Windows without rebooting Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows)) without success.

What **does** work is a simple Windows Hibernate. After restore, the shell becomes responsive with its history intact. If multiple shells are open, they all hang at the same time; returning from hibernation, they all become perfectly responsive.

It's not version specific: It happens about as often with 22.04 and prior LTS releases such as 18.04.

Is there any command / PS that can "poke" the subsystem back to awareness?

Comment: FYI: seems to be exactly the same/similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1713488/wsl-stops-responding.  What's additionally interesting is a reboot isn't necessary