# WSL2 unresponsive after idling

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Been running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (guest-machine) via WSL2 on Windows 11, but it frequently gets unresponsive to mouse/keyboard inputs after idling for a while (e.g. when I have to do some researches on the host so I stop operating the guest for a while).

It does not exactly freeze, as I can see text cursor still blinking etc, but since it gets unresponsive to inputs I cannot operate it anymore when it goes into this state. Going into this state also does not generate any errors or messages in the CMD prompt.

Not sure if this makes any difference but running on XFCE4 and viewing it with VcXsrv. When it happens, my computer does not seem to have a 100% CPU usage like some other users have reported online.

As commented on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1713488/372159), I tried `ps n -efH`, the output is as follows:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does `wsl --shutdown` work when this happens ?

Comment: @harrymc Yes it does.

Comment: Is Windows fully updated and is "Receive updates for other Microsoft products" is set in *Settings > Windows Update > Advanced options*?

Comment: @harrymc Yes it is.